# Can I ask about game exploits being patched?

Tags: discussion

So there is an exploit in Borderlands the Pre-Sequel and I was wondering if it was now patched but I am unable to verify it myself.

Would I be able to ask if anyone can verify that its patched on Gaming SE?

Here is a YouTube video that shows the exploit:

**Note:** I'm not asking for it to be answered here I'm just providing background for the real site.

Comment: I would *assume* you can. I've seen a couple Fallout 4 questions asking about things being fixed since the latest patch and those haven't been downvoted/flagged.

Comment: @DangerZone sweet, thanks for the reply.

Comment: I have no opinion either way, but with regards to your first comment: your question had only been up for one hour before you posted that. Even on the main site an hour is not a long time, and on meta it's entirely possible only one or two people had even read the question yet. Patience is required.

Comment: @ChrisHayes if its fine then its fine, no need to wait around. I need answers! Besides this site is extremely lacking in traffic, I'll be luck to get 50 views but the end of the day.

Comment: Sure, traffic isn't as heavy as say StackOverflow, but you also need to keep in mind that "Has X been patched" questions don't tend to be the most popular or widely viewed. Interesting questions about popular games definitely get attention. Even then, patience is still required as @ChrisHayes said. This goes with all SE sites.

Comment: @DangerZone Its no problem, I just wanted to be sure, the responses seemed positive so I went ahead, I don't mind if I don't get a response, just as long as I don't get downvotes. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. Asking whether something works in the current version of a game is definitely on-topic.

This would, however, only apply to questions about whether something has been patched. Questions about whether something will be patched (speculation) or why something has/hasn't been patched (developer intent) are still off-topic.

Comment: Unless of course it has been announced (officially) that it's going to be patched at x date.

Comment: @Oak In which case you wouldn't need to ask, since you'd already know.